# how to clone a Debian9 hard drive for use as image on QEMU host on Debian 11

Tags: linux, qemu, disk-image

I want to take an image of a 120Gb SSD used in an i7-7700 32Gb memory unit running Debian 9 and create an image to use via Virtual Machine Manager on Debian 11 unit i9-9900K with 64Mb. I tried `dd if=/dev/sda of=hdd.img bs=4M` and then `qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 hdd.img hdd.qcow2` I then create a new VM using import disk image option using the hdd.qcow2 file and set the ram to 32Gb and CPU's to 4 but it just sits on `Booting from Hard Disk ...` and doesn't progress.
Is there some logging somewhere I can see why it is not progressing or tools to check the image file(s) ?

Comment: on the image file, you'll need to reinstall the bootloader (i.e. grub I guess for Debian), adjust the fstab, disable any xorg stuff, and re-regenerate initramfs image

Comment: Why would you need to reinstall grub? The disk is the same under a VM.

Comment: can you clarify @JaromandaX if all those things are done to the .img or the .qcow2 and if so how? Or somehow under qemu (which does not boot so how can I)?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I did not say re-install grub, i said re-install  the bootloader - i.e. run `grub-install` and `update-grub` for example

Comment: @kalpha - you boot the VM using a bootable image (e.g. live cd, or some rescue system) mount the "disk", and do what you need using chroot etc - also, it may be a little more complex if you are using EFI

Comment: @JaromandaX ta. not familiar with chroot so will have to research. There is no U(EFI) involved in any of this. Out of interest... if the whole disk was imaged... why is it not bootable under QEMU? If I write the image back to a different disk and physically connect it to original unit it boots!

Comment: I've only ever done this with (U)EFI system, so, I I'm not sure if anything I suggested would be required to be honest.

Comment: I have booted a new VM from a Deb9 live iso and the qcow2 image mounted. I can see all the partitions there via gparted on /dev/vda and can mount the data related partitions and see content expected. But no sure what/where I am supposed to chroot to? and grub-install command not present in live image so don't know what I need to install to get. Still like to know why this would be needed if image was dd from the disk with it in first place?

Comment: so i tried this ...
`$sudo mount /dev/vda2 /mnt` `$sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev` `$sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc` `$sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys` `$sudo chroot /mnt bash` `#grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/vda`
but I got `grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory`
was that the right sort of thing to try ... or